# How to get features from a trained .caffemodel file?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, feature-extraction

I have trained the `.caffemodel` model from `.h5` file, which contains two components, one is image, another is a 3D vector. I was wondering if it is possible to get the `concat layer` feature from this `.caffemodel` and how?
I have `.h5` file, `.caffemodel` and `train_test.prototxt`.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/501) may help you.